# Correct way of using data attribute with f.button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

What is the correct syntax for using data attribute in form button.

```
  <%= f.button class: "btn", 'data-addr': 'blurred_email_<%= lead.id %>', id: "show-mail-btn"  do %> 
    Show Email
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to the following, you can use [`f.button`](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/745#issuecomment-13739016), [`button_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag) or [`button`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/button)

```
<%= button_tag class: "btn", data: "blurred_email_#{lead.id}", id: "show-mail-btn"  do %> 
    Show Email
<% end %>
```

Generated HTML

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn" data="blurred_email_1" id="show-mail-btn"> 
    Show Email
</button>
```

If you need to data disable after click then use like below

```
<%= button_tag class: "btn", data: { disable_with: "Loading..." }, id: "show-mail-btn" do %>
    Show Email
<% end %>
```

Generated HTML

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn" data-disable-with="Loading..." id="show-mail-btn"> 
    Show Email
</button>
```

See here the [API doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag)